# One button to call two different methods based on selected check box in Angular 6

Tags: angular

As a part of requirement, I need to create two check boxes and one button in my angular 6 project.

If first check box is checked then on clicking the button a function needs to be called and if the second check box is checked then on clicking the same button different functions should be called.

Comment: I guess you have to write some code to achieve that ;) So please show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

just the code to the mentioned solution of Saif Jerbi.

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox">
<button (click)="buttonClicked()">My Button </button>
```

Typescript:

```
public myCheckbox:boolean = false;
public buttonClicked():void{
  if( myCheckbox ){
    // call first method
  } else{
    // call second method
  }
}
```

warm regards
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You add one click handler to your button and inside this handler you could check whether to call the first function or the second one.

By this way, you keep your code cleaner